# Javascript display all elements of array except for the specified index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Out of curiosity, is there any way to display inverted array index. Let's say we got this as our array:

```
var color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
console.log(color[2]);
```

Of course the console will show "blue" right?

What if I want to display other than "blue"? That mean "red", "green", "yellow".
Or should we use slice instead?

Thank you

Comment: Use filter `["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"].filter((c,i) => i !== 2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` to filter out elements. So, in this case filter out all the elements of the array which is not blue.

```
var color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
console.log(color.filter(col => col !== "blue"));
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can use a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) here

```js
var color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
const result = color.filter((c) => c !== "blue");
console.log(result);
```

**2)** Although you can also use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
var color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];
const newArray = [...color];
newArray.splice(2, 1);
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right what you want, so show everything EXCEPT the one which's index you pass, then:

```
myFun = (myArray, n) => {
  return myArray.slice(0, n).concat(myArray.slice(n+1))
}
color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"]
myFun(color, 2)

// ["red", "green", "yellow"]
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can infer from your question is - you wish to pass in an index and get everything from the array except for the element at the index you passed, and whether there's a direct array helper that we can use. I think there's none so you might as well want to create your own :D

```
Array.prototype.invertedArrayWithIndex = function(indexOfChoice){
        var _array = this;
        return _array.filter(function(ele, index){
         return _array.indexOf(ele) !=  indexOfChoice
    })
}

var color = ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow"];

color.invertedArrayWithIndex(2); // Array(3) [ "red", "green", "yellow" ]
```